# load screenshot from adb through c#

Tags: c#, adb, emgucv

I want to get a screenshot into c# using adb without saving files to the filesystem all the time.
I'm using the SharpAdbClient to talk with the device.
I'm on a windows platform.

This is what i got so far:

```
AdbServer server = new AdbServer();
StartServerResult result = server.StartServer(@"path\to\adb.exe", restartServerIfNewer: false);
DeviceData device = AdbClient.Instance.GetDevices().First();
ConsoleOutputReceiver receiver = new ConsoleOutputReceiver();
AdbClient.Instance.ExecuteRemoteCommand("screencap -p", device, receiver);
string str_image = receiver.ToString().Replace("\r\r", "");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str_image);
Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

I can successfully load both str_image, and create the byte array but it keeps saying   System.ArgumentException when trying to load it into an Image.

I also tried saving the data to a file, but the file is corrupt.
I tried both replacing "\r\r" and "\r\n", both same result.

Anyone has some insight in how to load this file?
It's actually preferred if it could be loaded into a Emgu image since i'm gonna do some CV on it later.

Comment: What is the value of `str_image` after replacing \r\r?

Comment: A long string but with no double carriage returns.

Comment: Is the string be base64 encoded?

Comment: No. I think it’s binary. If you open a png file in a text editor. It looks very much like that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the [nonprintable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) in the string.

Look at the code below

```
string str_image = File.ReadAllText("test.png");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str_image);

byte[] actualBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("test.png");
```

`str_image` is shown in the below screencap, note that there are some non-printable chars (displayed as question mark).

The [first eight bytes of a PNG file](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) are always

> 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10

While you read the console output as a string, then use ASCII to encode the string, the first byte becomes 63 (0x3F), which is the ASCII code for a question mark.

Also note that the size of the two byte arrays vary hugely (7828/7378).

And other thing is you are replace "\r\r", while actually a new line character in Windows is "\r\n".

So my conclusion is some image data is lost or modified in the output redirection by the `ConsoleOutputReceiver`, and you cannot recover the original data from the output string.

[image]